# Knowing caller class with AspectJ

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm trying to imitate Spring's [AspectJ @Async support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) but with a message bus.

The issue is I need to know if my Message Bus (RabbitMQ MessageListener) is calling the method  or a normal (all others) caller where the method will return instantly.

*My annotation is called @MQAsync instead of Springs @Async.*

```
package com.snaphop.mqueue;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.snaphop.mqueue.MQAsync;

public aspect MQAsyncAspect {

    //pointcut asyncTypeMarkedMethod() : execution(@MQAsync void *(..));
    pointcut asyncTypeMarkedMethod() : call(@MQAsync void *(..));

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("MQAsync");

    Object around() : asyncTypeMarkedMethod() {     
        if (listenerIsCaller) {
            return proceed();
        }
        //Send the method parameters to the message bus.
        //this logic isn't here for brevity.
        return null;
    }
}
```

The *call* pointcut will get me the caller context but that will not work as I will be calling the method with my message listener through reflection. The *execution* pointcut (commented out) will not tell me who is calling the method.

**Is there a way to determine the caller class maybe through some sort of stack dump analysis?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can determine which class is invoking the current method with the following call.  Note that you'll have to catch `ClassNotFoundException` (unless you're satisfied simply retrieving the name as a `String`).

```
Class.forName(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getClassName());
```

Why the third element?  Because the stack is ordered like so when the stack trace method is invoked:

1. `Thread#getStackTrace()`
2. *`CurrentClass.currentMethod`*`()`
3. *`ParentClass.parentMethod`*`()`

Comment: I was figuring it would be something like this but I was nervous that it would be rather unpredictable because of the AspectJ advice. That is the stacktrace needs to ignore aspectj advice. I supposed I could just do getStackTrace()[3] or getStackTrace[4] etc... through trial and error.

Comment: I think it's worth saying here that using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` is much slower than getting the stack trace via `new Throwable().getStackTrace()`  See http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6375302

Answer (score 10):

Actually *cheeken*'s answer is nice, but for AspectJ `call()` pointcuts you can get the calling class much more easily and without ugly reflection:

```java
thisEnclosingJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType()
```

Please consider to accept this answer if you think it is better than the other one, otherwise just enjoy the power of AspectJ. `;-)`

Comment: Ah, thanks, I thought there was a better, AspectJ-way of getting this data. I actually need the whole stack trace, not just a calling method. Is there a method for that? Thanks again, upvote.

Comment: +1 however if you read my question carefully I'm calling the method through reflection (akin to Spring MVC routing) so this will not work as that information is not compiled in.

Comment: True. In that case, getting the call stack via a new `Throwable` instance is the more appropriate course of action.

Comment: I'm betting this is way faster than generating an exception or stack trace. All I needed is the caller name so this is great.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative that seems more light since is native and commonly used by the SecurityManager. To use it we need a utility class because the the method we need is protected.

```
public class CallStackUtils extends SecurityManager {

  static CallStackUtils sm = new CallStackUtils();

  public Class[] getCallersClassesStack0() {
    return getClassContext();
  }

  static public Class[] getCallersClassesStack() {
    return sm.getCallersClassesStack0();
  }

}
```